# Check for valid statistics

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Alice conducted a voting about N of his opinions. A[i] percent of people voted for opinion number i.

This statistics is called valid if sum of all A[i] is equal to 100.

Now let us define rounding up of a statistics A.

If A[i] is not an integer, it will be rounded up to next integer. 
Otherwise it will be left as it is.

e.g. 4.1 became 5,

4.9 became 5 but 6 will still be 6.

Now let us consider a statistics B of size N in which each of B[i] is an integer. Now she wants to know where there exists some valid statistic A of size N (may contain real numbers) such that after rounding it up, it becomes same as B?

Example : Let N=3 and array B =[30,30,30] then answer is NO as there can not be any A which could be rounded up to get B. Hence answer is NO.

Also let N=2 and array be [50,51] then answer is YES as A = {49.5,50.5}. After rounding up we get {50,51} which is equal to B. Hence answer is YES.

What can be efficient algorithm to check this ?

Comment: Is there any algorithm fr this ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the following.

*Proposition.* Let $B$ be a statistics of size $N$ in which each $B_i$ is an integer. Then there exists a valid statistic $A$ of size $N$ such that after rounding it up, it becomes $B$ iff $100\le B<100+N.$

*Proof.* The necessity is obvious. To prove the sufficiency put $A_i=B_i-(B-100)/N$ for each $i$.